# Difference between rm my-symlink and rm my-symlink/

Tags: symlink, rm

Just wanted to know why if I use `rm -rf my-symlink` it deletes the symbolic link only but `rm -rf my-symlink/` deletes the files within the linked directory and leaves the symbolic link alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the difference by comparing the output of `stat my-symlink` and `stat my-symlink/`. `my-symlink`, without the slash, is the symbolic link itself; `my-symlink/`, with the slash, is the directory pointed to by the symbolic link, which you can verify separately by comparing the inodes of `my-symlink/` and of the directory it points to.

With that information in hand, the behaviour you’re seeing matches that described in [`rm`’s specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html): when processing a symbolic link, `rm` deletes the link without descending “into” it if it points to a directory; when processing a directory (with the `-r` option), it deletes its contents recursively. In the `my-symlink/` case, `rm` does try to delete the “directory”, but fails since it’s not a directory but a symbolic link — however because of the `-f` flag this doesn’t cause an error.

Comment: Actually, if you remove the `-f` flag, `rm` will report `ENOTDIR` on `my-symlink/`, suggesting that it is indeed trying to process it. I have a feeling this is due to the way `rm` uses `fts`: at first, `my-symlink/` is followed and the target is emptied. Then, `rm` tries to call `unlinkat` with `AT_REMOVEDIR` on the original path, which fails because it's actually a file (symlink). Because it was able to recurse with FTS from the original path, `rm` assumes it refers to a directory, and ignores the possibility of it being a symlink it previously followed seemlessly when recursing.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @John, that makes more sense (and does indeed match the behaviour seen with `strace`).

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would investigate the behaviour a little bit more, so here's another answer.

Internally, `rm` uses [FTS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) to recursive into file hierarchies. `fts_open` takes an array of paths as a parameter, and creates a tree structure for each path. This allows the programmer to explore several locations seemlessly as though they were part of one unified hierarchy.

Here's a test program you can use to play with FTS yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fts.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char* const* arr = argv + 1;
    FTS* hier = fts_open(arr, FTS_NOSTAT | FTS_PHYSICAL, NULL);

    FTSENT* ent;
    while((ent = fts_read(hier))) {
        printf("%s info=%d (D=%d DP=%d F=%d SL=%d)\n",
               ent->fts_accpath, ent->fts_info,
               ent->fts_info == FTS_D, ent->fts_info == FTS_DP,
               ent->fts_info == FTS_F || ent->fts_info == FTS_NSOK,
               ent->fts_info == FTS_SL);
    }

    fts_close(hier);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Let's assume we've created the following directory structure:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/file
$ ln -s dir sym
```

Now, let's consider your first case, and see how FTS leads the exploration.

```
$ gcc fts.c 
$ ./a.out sym
sym info=12 (D=0 DP=0 F=0 SL=1)
```

As you can see, in this case, `sym` is seen as a file. A symlink, to be more exact. With this information, `rm` would therefore treat it as a file, and call `unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "sym", 0)`. The last parameter (0) causes `unlinkat` to behave like `unlink`. In other words: it simply deletes a file. As a result, your link disappears.

Now, let's have a look at what happens with `sym/`.

```
$ ./a.out sym/
sym/ info=1 (D=1 DP=0 F=0 SL=0)
file info=11 (D=0 DP=0 F=1 SL=0)
sym/ info=6 (D=0 DP=1 F=0 SL=0)
```

In this case, `sym` was treated as its target directory. We first iterate to `sym`, then `sym/file` then `sym` again. This last one is due to how FTS works: first, it iterates over the contents, then comes back to the root node. This is actually pretty convenient for `rm`. In the first pass (`D`), it can erase files, and in the second (`DP`) remove the empty directories.

As you can see, in this case, FTS reports `sym/` as being a directory in both cases. This is because we gave the path with a trailing slash, which forces the kernel to interpret it as a directory. In the case of a link, this means it is going to follow it no matter what. [In more technical terms, the specs say:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)

> A pathname that contains at least one non-slash character and that ends with one or more trailing slashes shall be resolved as if a single dot character ( '.' ) were appended to the pathname.

Because FTS reports `sym/` as a directory, `rm` behaves as though it were deleting an empty directory. Accordingly, it calls `unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "sym/", AT_REMOVEDIR)`. This causes `unlinkat` to behave like `rmdir`.

However, upon resolving the `sym/` path, the `unlinkat` system call will realise that it is not, in fact, being given a directory. It will therefore report `ENOTDIR`, which triggers:

```
$ rm: cannot remove ‘sym/’: Not a directory
```

And actually, if you remove the `-f` flag from your calls... That's exactly what you'll see. Now, whether or not this is a bug or a feature... I have no idea.